# Rails - Changing boolean in database from js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, database, facebook, boolean

In my scenario in rails application after sharing content to facebook i will get a response object with post id

```
post_id: "mypostidhere"
```

If its not successful i will get response object with an error message.

So according to the response i want to change a boolean column of last row for the current user in my database table. And for this in my **.js.erb** file i tried to access **current_user.model.last** but it throws the following error.

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for
```

So how can i change the boolean column in database according to the response?

**UPDATED**

Ajax code

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/action"
    });
```

Controller code

```
def action
  current_user.modal.last.toggle!(:boolean-column-name)
end
```

It changes the table column successfully. But after that i am receiving an error in browser CONSOLE as below

```
POST http://URL/action
500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I am new to AJAX. What i am doing wrong in ajax request? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` is not a local variable to your JS function/file, it is a helper provided and available in your rails application.

So, what I will like to ask is:

> How are you using `current_user` in the JS file?

What you can do is to make an `ajax` call to a controller method, and then access `current_user` directly from the controller.

Comment: Thanks @SunnyK Currently trying the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the db, you're going to have to communicate with your Rails app, which is done with `ajax`:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
... // your events will fire
$.ajax({
   url: "/users/update",
   method: "PUT",
   data: { param: "value" }
   success: function(data) {
      // do something here
   };
});
```

This will allow you to do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   put :update, on: :collection
end

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def update
      current_user.update(update_params)
   end

   private

   def update_params
       params.permit(:param)
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed exp @Rich . I did it with AJAX to change the boolean value in the controller(not any updating stuffs) and it changes successfully but after that i receive an 500 server error in console. Updated in question.