# Rails form_tag routing to non-Restful action without including name of action in url on the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form_tag in `index.html.erb` which must route to an action update_multiple for updating DB with selection in the form. But there are multiple issues all interconnected to form and routes.

Issue 1: despite giving the action explicitly and method as PUT in form_tag, it takes _method as delete and goes on to destroy action. I'm not sure if index form doesn't take non-restful action.

Upon clicking submit the error is:

> {"utf8"=>"✓","_method"=>"delete","authenticity_token"=>"e/NgCpW+PQ==","true"=>"{:value=>nil}","false"=>"{:value=>nil}","cv_attachment_id"=>"33","commit"=>"Select Main","user_id"=>"97","id"=>"update_multiple"}

the cv_attachment_id is of the record selected but what is the last id and what should it be for normal operation and what are true and false which are both set to nil?

form code in index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag update_multiple_user_cv_attachments_path, method: :put, action: :update_multiple do %>
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> Select a CV </th>
            <th> Resume Name </th>
            <th> Creation Date </th>
            <th> Delete Resume </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <% @cv_attachments.each do |cv_attachment| %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag cv_attachment.main, :value => params[:main] %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= radio_button_tag "cv_attachment_ids[]", cv_attachment.id, cv_attachment.main %> </td>
            <td><%= cv_attachment.attachment.file.basename %></td>
            <td><%= cv_attachment.posting_date %></td>
            <td><%= button_to "Delete", user_cv_attachment_path(current_user, cv_attachment), method: "delete", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-danger btn-outline btn-md" %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <%= submit_tag "Select Main", :class =>'button' %>
     <% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
#resources :cv_attachments, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :create, :new, :destroy,]

resources :cv_attachments do
  collection do
    put 'update_multiple'
  end
end
```

Issue 2: As you can see I have specified 2 cv_attachments for Restful and non-restful actions and because it screwed up the routes, I had to comment the Restful ones so how to have both of them.

Issue 3: Also by doing collection and put it's adding update_multiple to end of url after clicking submit like:

http://localhost:3000/users/97/cv_attachments/update_multiple

but I do not want the action name in url: http://localhost:3000/users/97/cv_attachments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Margo thx again for I've taken your inputs. I figured out why form went to destroy instead of going to update. Actually there was a button_to for deleting attachment and as soon as I changed to link_to the form went to the right controller method.And I never suspected an innocuous looking button which was not 'form Submit'-button, was the culprit!

Here's the solution: routes.rb

```
resources :cv_attachments, only: [:index, :show, :create, :new, :destroy] do
collection do
  put 'update_multiple'
end
```

end

index.html--only giving  part of form

```
<tbody>
          <% @cv_attachments.each do |cv_attachment| %>
            <% if cv_attachment.main %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag "ex_main", cv_attachment.id %>
            <% end %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= radio_button_tag "new_main", cv_attachment.id, cv_attachment.main, :id => "#{cv_attachment.id}"%> </td>
              <td><%= cv_attachment.attachment.file.basename %></td>
              <td><%= cv_attachment.posting_date %></td>
              <td><%= link_to "Delete", user_cv_attachment_path(current_user, cv_attachment), method: "delete", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-danger btn-outline btn-md" %></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
```

Controller:

```
def update_multiple
if request.put?
  if params["ex_main"] != params["new_main"]
    CvAttachment.find(params[:ex_main]).toggle!(:main)
    CvAttachment.find(params[:new_main]).toggle!(:main)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to create a member route on users.

routes

```
 resources :users do
  member do
    post :update_main_attachment
  end
end
```

form

```
<%= form_tag update_main_attachment_user_path do %>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @cv_attachments.each do |cv_attachment| %>
      <% if cv_attachment.main %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag "ex_main_cv", cv_attachment.id %>
      <% end %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= radio_button_tag "main_cv", cv_attachment.id, cv_attachment.main %> </td>
        <td><%= cv_attachment.attachment.file.basename %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
<% end %>
```

To answer your 2nd issue, you can nest collection routes under resourceful routes:

```
resources :cv_attachments, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :create, :new, :destroy,] do
  collection do
    put 'update_multiple'
  end
end
```

For your 3rd issue, you can give the collection route a name using the `:as` option. Refer to [the Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers).

Comment: Thx, Margo. I didnot understand why two routes you have specified one as member and the other as collection. Anyway I put in both collection and member with different names as you gave but

Comment: Anyway I put in both collection and member with different names as you gave but error: No route matches {:action=>"update_main_attachment", :controller=>"cv_attachments", :user_id=>"97"} missing required keys: [:id].I then took off member and added collection. The error is: update_multiple_user_cv_attachments_path. It's akin to Index-put issue.Coders used hacks back then 7 years ago.I can't believe it still is not fixed so is it that index is only read-only. I guess I had this issue and I tackled with show.html.will try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772011/rails-restful-actions-index-put

Comment: Well! the error with just collections is: undefined local variable or method update_multiple_user_cv_attachments_path although it takes that name in form. With neither of those solutions, the form is loading. It's akin to the classic Index-Put issue as described in my last comment maybe index is read-only.I'm sure exp coders like u have come across this.How did you tackle it?I'll try with show.html or post another question.

Comment: Re your original questions, I addressed each in isolation, hence why I used collection and member routes. Re a solution: I used a member route on the user resource as you are updating attachments which belong to a specific user. The member route and the form as shown in my original answer works. You will need to create a controller action similar to my answer to your other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457718/rails-5-form-tag-with-original-db-value-and-after-new-selection-in-form-both-re

Comment: If I do the member way, there'll be 2 problems --1)collection of data cannot be passed.As I'm using radio-buttons and not check-boxes so it's ok even if 1 object is passed.2) logically form will look for update_main_attachment in users controller but as I'm using devise for user authentication, there's no users controller.I can override devise but not sure how for this case.Again,@cv_attachments will not be accessible in users controller so I have to put in cv_attachments as nested route. Not sure if you forgot to mention something else for it to work.Nevertheless, many many thx :-)

Comment: I have tried so many combinations with form_tag-index-put-collection and finally decided to try AJAX way as I'm unable to decipher how PUT is getting interpreted. So, looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331727/rails-changing-boolean-in-database-from-js-erb-file. if @margo / anyone has any AJAX or JSON solution, kindly put it down.

Comment: The solution I posted works alongside the controller solution I posted in response to your other question which I linked to in my previous comment. It is acceptable to use the 'post' verb as you are updating multiple records. Regards an ajax solution, you would be best placed to start another thread.